# AngularJS use Data from Function inside a Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service to get User data. 
The returned data shall be used in a controller.

My problem is, that I can't access the data from `db.find` inside the `getUsers()` function.

**Service**

```
 app.service('userService', function(){

 this.getUsers = function() {

      var users;

     //neDB find all Users in DB
     db.find({}, function (err, data) {
       queryReturn(data);
     });

     function queryReturn(data) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
       return data;
     }
   };
});
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope, userService) {

    $scope.users = '';
    $scope.users = userService.getUsers();
    console.log("Users " + $scope.users);

});
```

Can anyone give help out with this?

**EDIT:**

I changed the code in the Service and now I get all the data I want when calling `getUsers()`. BUT how can I access this data in my controller? It always returns: undefined..

Comment: need to return a promise in the getUsers method, its async

Comment: I don't see that db is declared anywhere.

Comment: You said Angular but you seem to be using mongo too, can you explain better what are you using? angular+meteor maybe? mean.io?

Comment: I changed the Service and its working now within the Service. But how can I access the data in my controller? @DanielNalbach I left out the DB declation. This is not the problem. I use angular with neDB.